# biblatex IEEE bibliography style: Alphabetical labels rather than numerical labels

Tags: biblatex, ieee-style

I am having a problem with biblatex, where the citations look like [XYZ05] but the entries in the bibliography are simply numeric like [1]. Here are my package options:

```
\usepackage[firstinits=false,sorting=none,bibstyle=ieee,
citestyle=alphabetic,maxnames=99,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false]{biblatex}
```

and I generate the bibliography with calls like

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,keyword=conference,title=Conferences]
```

You can see the generated file at http://dave-pritchard.net/tmp/cv.pdf and notice that the hyperlinks from citations to bibliographic entries even work! So the things are connected in some sense, it is just the superficial label in the bibliography which is printing wrong. What could cause printbibliography to ignore my citestyle?

Updated as per Marco's comment: I am using [ieee.bbx](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ieee/ieee.bbx) as a bibstyle (in fact a derivative but the problem is equally bad with either). So I hope the problem is better phrased as:

> in ieee.bbx, how can I change the labels attached to each
>   bibliographic entry, to be the same as in alphabetic.cbx?

Comment: *What could cause printbibliography to ignore my citestyle?* -- I think your definition. Sorry but nobody knows your `bibstyle`. Please provide a minimal example.

Comment: @Marco: thanks. I had no idea that the .cbx and .bbx file would each provide their own way of generating labels, to me it's a weird system. Anyway I still have a problem but I hope it's phrased clearly now, please see the revision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the IEEE use a numerical style, you will need to add some code from alphabetical styles into your source. Add the `labelalpha` option to those used when loading `biblatex`, to come *after* the `bibstyle=ieee` option, and add the following code after loading `biblatex`:

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelalpha}%
        \printfield{extraalpha}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelalphawidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
```

Comment: If this is not quite right, a short minimal example would be useful.

Comment: It does work, you are Wright! It also seems to work just as well when I append it to my .bbx file, which is nice since I don't need to add it again to my next latex source file. Thanks!

Comment: @daveagp I assume your `.bbx` is a copy of `ieee.bbx`, as it's never a good idea to alter the one in your TeX distribution directly.